# I am a tax resident of a "tax haven" country. When another government asks me for my tax statements, what do I provide to them?

Tags: tax-law, turkey

There's a tax amnesty law in this country that benefits people who kept their business / capital activity abroad. For example, you're a 3D designer working for a UK company from this country or you're an investor or a business owner (a pass through entity). You get paid to your non-local account. You don't bring that money back to the country until the government publishes a tax amnesty law. Using that law, you can pay 0-3% percent tax on that money to bring it to the country. If you brought the money into the country without making use of this law, you'd be taxed at 30-45%.

Here's some info about the tax amnesty. (I couldn't find anything in English. If you have Chrome, you can translate it easily by right click in the page)

https://www.pwc.com.tr/tr/hizmetlerimiz/vergi/bultenler/2022/varlik-barisi-genel-tebligi-yayimlandi.html

https://www.ey.com/tr_tr/tax/varlik-barisi-bu-kez-vergili

Note that you don't have to bring this money back to the country (the tax amnesty laws seem to imply that). The government started to publish these laws 14 years ago iirc and it's very likely that they'll keep doing this. The political environment is the same as well as the administration. So if you really want to buy something local like a house or a car, then you can bring it. Otherwise you can just use your foreign credit/debit card for most stuff. You can use foreign brokers to invest in equities and REITs etc.

Note that in this country, there's no such thing as filing taxes personally. To file taxes, you must create a company first and you do it through that entity. If you're an employee of a local company, they handle filing for you and you don't do anything about filing taxes.

My question:

Sometimes you need to provide tax statements for other governments when you want to apply for a residence permit for example. They want to see how much you earned and what % of it was taxes, especially if they require a something like 100K/y for qualification for the visa or permit. In this case, what should I be providing?

Side question: Sometimes foreign banks require such documents to open an account for you. What can I provide to them?

Comment: Are they asking for specific form numbers?  Give them those form numbers then, or ask them what information they need and find documents with that information.  Then provide those documents. Follow up to ensure it is sufficient for their needs.

Comment: This may be better asked on the [money.SE](https://money.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You may simply have a problem applying from a tax haven country. Not all laws are fair to people in outlier legal regimes, especially when the laws are domestic ones drafted to regulate foreigners.